# Can't install from pypi with pip

Tags: python, django, pip

I am a package maintainer and have a library on pip - [Django-spaghetti-and-meatballs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-spaghetti-and-meatballs/0.2.0).

- Its at version 0.2.0
- [It is listed on pip as version 0.2.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-spaghetti-and-meatballs/0.2.0)
- [`setup.py` imports some code that clearly states it is version 0.2.0](https://github.com/LegoStormtroopr/django-spaghetti-and-meatballs/blob/master/django_spaghetti/__init__.py)

But when users try to run `pip install django-spaghetti-and-meatballs==0.2.0` they (and I) get:

```
legostormtroopr:~/workspace $ pip install django-spaghetti-and-meatballs==0.2.0
Downloading/unpacking django-spaghetti-and-meatballs==0.2.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-spaghetti-and-meatballs==0.2.0 (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.0rc5, 0.1.1)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for django-spaghetti-and-meatballs==0.2.0
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log
```

What have I done wrong?

---

PS. It feels a little spammy to link to the library and such, but its a problem and I felt it better to point to the problem directly.

Comment: How did you upload the package to pypi?

Comment: The wheel doesn't seem to have made it: https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-spaghetti-and-meatballs/

Comment: Oh bother, I must have skipped a step on the last release. Help?

Comment: So have you tried `python setup.py bdist_wheel upload` yet?

Comment: Nope, I must have skipped that one crucial step last time. I did that, and now everything works. If you add I as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the list at: https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-spaghetti-and-meatballs/ you could see that the wheel had not been uploaded.

Running:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel upload
```

will rebuild the wheel and upload it.